# How Can I Determine When a USER last restarted a windows pc

Tags: boot, user

I would like to know when a USER last INTENTIONALLY restarted a windows machine.  There are other posts relative to this but the source of the restart is not clear to me.  Thank you.

Comment: The first answer to this Question shows the different kind of Events that are recorded.   https://superuser.com/questions/767143/find-out-why-pc-just-restarted-for-no-reason .  Event 1074 appears to be the one from user intentionally choosing "Shut Down".  Feel free to test it on your own PC with a known Windows Update restart, and another via manual restart, and write up an Answer with your findings.  This might also be useful : https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-the-shutdown-event-tracker-in-windows-7